# In Word 2016, can I hide resolved comments when printing markup?

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

We use Track Changes and comments extensively - with anywhere from 2-10 people working on a single, large document. We would like to periodically print a list of *just* the comments to review open/outstanding items - but it shows no difference for comments that are resolved vs open.

(We choose only comments to show in markup, go to Print, scroll down to "List of Markup", voila just a list of comments.)

We don't want to just delete resolved comments.

Is there a way to have it mark the comments' status or put resolved items in a different color? I'm happy to write a macro but don't even know where to begin.

Comment: in case someone is willing to accept deleting the comments when done.  Here's a macro https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2016/can-you-remove-only-resolved-comments-in-word-2016/a8f067a7-4d7e-4571-805a-64900942612c